# Cannot populate my request body for testing signup functionality with Postman *FIXED*

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cloudinary

I am developing a very bare bones social media app, where users can signup, login, create posts, edit their profile and their posts, delete posts and delete themselves entirely.

Tokens via jwt should be created and used appropriately and users will upload all related files to cloudinary. Where profile pictures are stored in a profile_pictures folder and posts in a user_posts folder.

All of this used to work when tested last friday. However now, out of nowhere when I sat down to fix the tokens on the frontend side, I suddenly couldn't signup a user anymore. So I went to the backend, checked the code, went to Postman, tested the route and it doesn't populate the request body.

Now there are more issues than that, for example the file upload to cloudinary is not working anymore either and I do not know if that is due to recent API updates on their end, even though on their page it says "Last Updated 15th of June" and my last signup and login tests were on friday the 16th of June, which makes me think that if it worked then it should still work now. But it doesn't.

All of that is not why I am posing this question and seeking aid, though. I have disabled all of the file upload related code in my app to just test the creation of a user object to mongo db atlas.

And here is where my problem lies. For some reason beyond my scope of knowledge and understanding Postman will not populate anything via form-data, even though everything is seemingly in order, the content-type is correct, the fields of the user object to be created are correct.

It will solely populate it if I use the raw input in Postman. And I am at my wits end here...

Please if anyone knows anything about this issue, I would be deeply grateful for your help.

Here is the related code, please ignore the commented out file related code lines.

```
// AUTH CONTROLLER:
// controller for user signup
module.exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body, "req body");
        // retrieve user from db by email provided in request body
        const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        console.log(foundUser, "found user");
        // check if foundUser already exists in db
        if (foundUser) {
            res.status(409).json({ message: `Email already in use. Please choose another.` });
        }
        // generate salt and hash for the user password
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(Number(process.env.SALT_ROUND));
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);
        // create a new user object from user model
        const newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hash,
            //profilePicture: req.file.path
        });
        // console.log(req.file, "req file");
        await newUser.save(); // save the new user object to the database
        // upload the profile picture to cloudinary storage
        // const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
        //     public_id: `profile_pictures/${newUser._id}`,
        // });
        //newUser.profilePicture = result.secure_url;
        //await newUser.save(); // update newUser with the profilePicture URL
        console.log(newUser, "new user");
        // generate a signup token
        // const token = jwt.sign({ newUserId: newUser._id, newUserName: newUser.username, newUserProfilePicture: newUser.profilePicture }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        //     expiresIn: '5m' // expires in 5 minutes (in case signup was erroneous)
        // });
        // store the token as a cookie
        // res.cookie('jwt', token, {
        //     httpOnly: true
        // });
        // respond with the newly created user object and the created token
        res.status(201).json({ message: `User created successfully!`, user: newUser });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    };
};
```

```
// AUTH ROUTE:
// import dependencies
const express = require('express')
const authController = require('../controllers/authController')
//const authHandler = require('../middlewares/authHandler')

// create new router object
const router = express.Router()

// import controllers
router.post('/signup', authController.signup)
//router.post('/login', authController.login)
//router.get('/logout', authHandler.checkUser, authController.logout)

module.exports = router
```

```
// USER MODEL:
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, unique: true },
  //profilePicture: { type: String },
})

// usually you hash/salt inside the appropriate model; like our userModel here.
//
// but we save the user-object twice for following two reasons:
// - the regular data of the user-object gets saved to our mongoDB atlas database.
// - and the profile picture gets uploaded and saved in an appropriate folder to cloudinary.
//
// this triggers the password hash twice, which in return falsifies the user password on login attempt.
// therefore we ignore the code snippet below and directly salt and hash in our authController.
//
// hash and salt user password before saving to database
// UserSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
// const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
// this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
// next();
// });

// pre-hook for updating password field
UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
  const update = this.getUpdate()
  if (update.password) {
    bcrypt.hash(update.password, Number(process.env.SALT_ROUND), function (err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err)
      update.password = hash
      next()
    })
  }
})

// compare the password entered by the user with the hashed password in the database
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err) //cb(err) passes errors down to error handler the same way next(err) does
    cb(null, isMatch)
  })
}

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)

module.exports = User
```

```
// SERVER:
// import dependencies
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// import routes (modules)
const authRoute = require('./routes/authRoute');
const userRoute = require('./routes/userRoute');
const postRoute = require('./routes/postRoute');

const app = express(); // initialize express

// import middlewares
const { connectMongoDB } = require('./lib/mongoose'); // destruct mongoDB connector
const { errorHandler } = require('./middlewares/errorHandler'); // destruct errorHandler

// allow requests from specified origins with specific methods
const whitelist = [process.env.FRONTEND_URL, 'https://www.arii.me'];

// add cors options
const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('CORS issues'));
    };
  },
  credentials: true,
};

// enable cross-origin resource sharing with specified options for the express app
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse incoming cookies and make them accessible in req.cookies
app.use(cookieParser());

// enable parsing of incoming JSON data in the request body by the express app
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// define routes
app.use('/auth', authRoute);
app.use('/users', userRoute);
app.use('/posts', postRoute);

// define middlewares
connectMongoDB();
app.use(errorHandler); // error handler must be last invoked middleware

// listen to server
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3003, () => {
  console.log(`Server up and running at ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

```
// MONGOOSE:
// import dependencies
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

// destruct envs
const { DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_NAME } = process.env;

// atlas connection string
const mongoURI = `mongodb+srv://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@${DB_HOST}/${DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

// middleware function for handling connections to the mongoDB atlas database
module.exports.connectMongoDB = async () =>{
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        console.log(`Connected to MongoDB Atlas!`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Couldn't Connect to MongoDB Atlas!`);
        next(err);
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is too much, but this is all the related code and I am losing my mind.
I know it is not wise to lay bare the ENVs but this is just an exercise for myself anyway therefore I have no qualms to share the ENVs.

I am very grateful for any and all input on this matter.

**UPDATE**:

I have fixed the issue of the request body not being populated with following code:

```
// In the auth route I imported multer:
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer()
// Then I added a method to the auth route before signup is called:
router.post('/signup', upload.none(), authController.signup)
// I have also forfeited any file upload during signup
// and replaced them with a default image in my cloudinary assets.
// Here's the updated userModel profilePicture field:
profilePicture: { type: String, default: 'res.cloudinary.com/ddb2abwuu/image/upload/v1687256495/…' }
```

By doing these steps it now correctly populates the request body and I can create users again with Postman form-data and on the frontend, too.

The users can choose to change the default profilePicture with an upload of their own later through a patch route. Other websites handle user acquistion in a similar way.

Don't ask me why I have to do these mental gymnastics suddenly, when it all worked as it was just a few days ago but here we are.

I have a strong suspicion that at least one of the packages and dependencies I use have had some kind of API update that completely screwed me over.

As it stands this ticket is now solved. Hopefully this will be useful to anyone suffering from the same bizarre issue in the future.

Comment: What error or exception are you receiving from the Cloudinary API or SDK, assuming that's where the error is?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have disabled all cloudinary related code to just boil it down to saving data to my mongo db atlas. I have correctly destructured the user model fields to populate the request body, the content type in Postman is set to "multiform/form-data" as it should.
This way I am excluding all file upload related code and merely want the mongodb related code to function. But as I mentioned Postman simply refuses to populate the request body appropriately via form-data, however via raw json input Postman gladly executes the request.
The error I get is an empty request body.

Comment: Because it fails to populate the req.body, it also fails the hashing and salting of the password, resulting in this error stack:

{ } req body -> this was my attempt to log the request body
Error: data and salt arguments required at...

Comment: @ElongatedMucus Not related to the issue - but since you had included the Secrets in "ENVs" section of your question, you will want to disable that API Key/Secret pair in your Cloudinary account (Settings > Access Keys) and generate a new Key/Secret pair to use in your app. Also rotating your JWT and DB credentials.

Comment: @Aleksandar you mean just as a safety measure, right? Or are they now immediately nonfunctional after being exposed? Since I see they've been "REMOVED". Sorry I am very new here and this is my first ever ticket.

Comment: @ElongatedMucus - They are removed but they appear in Edit History. They are not automatically non-functional and can still be used. For this reason, to prevent 3rd party access to your Cloudinary/DB etc, it's important to disable the existing credentials and generate new ones.

Comment: As of now I have found a solution which is mindboggling to me:


In my authRoute I have to explicitly import multer

then create const upload = multer()


then in the route specify:

router.post('/signup', upload.none(), authController.signup)


I have also forfeited any file uploads during signup and just manually added a default profile picture to my cloudinary assets, which I included to my userModel:

profilePicture: { type: String, default: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ddb2abwuu/image/upload/v1687256495/default_lhymg4.png' }

Like this both Signup and Login work again.

Comment: @ElongatedMucus - Were you able to disable the current API Key/Secret pair and generate a new one for Cloudinary?

Comment: @Alkesandar honestly I have been too lazy to do that :P I just removed the ENVs from the ticket. The issue is resolved. But thanks for your concern.

Comment: @ElongatedMucus - It's not really fixed since they still show under the Stack Overflow Edit History of your question. The API Secret which is sensitive and should be kept secure (+ Cloud Name and API Key which are not sensitive pieces of data) will allow anyone to access your Cloudinary cloud - effectively it's now public unless these credentials are disabled and you generate new ones that are kept secure.

Comment: @Aleksandar Ahh okay! I was under the illusion that if I edit the ticket and remove them they are gone. I will update the secrets then. It doesn't take long anyway. Thanks again. Do you know how I can flag this ticket as answered? Couldn't find a designated button or anything.

EDIT: I found the button. Sorry for being such a noob, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now I have found a solution which is mindboggling to me: In my authRoute I have to explicitly import multer then create

```
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer()
```

then in the auth route specify:

```
router.post('/signup', upload.none(), authController.signup)
```

I have also forfeited any file uploads during signup and just manually added a default profile picture to my cloudinary assets, which I included to my user model:

```
profilePicture: { type: String, default: 'res.cloudinary.com/ddb2abwuu/image/upload/v1687256495/…' }
```

Like this both Signup and Login work again.

By doing these steps it now correctly populates the request body and I can create users again with Postman form-data and on the frontend, too.

The users can choose to change the default profilePicture with an upload of their own later through a patch route. Other websites handle user acquistion in a similar way.

Don't ask me why I have to do these mental gymnastics suddenly, when it all worked as it was just a few days ago but here we are.

I have a strong suspicion that at least one of the packages and dependencies I use have had some kind of API update that completely screwed me over.

As it stands this ticket is now solved. Hopefully this will be useful to anyone suffering from the same bizarre issue in the future.